# SAS PROC SQL Group by all variables to detect duplicates

Tags: sas, duplicates, proc-sql

I have a dataset that contains 250 variables. I think some rows may be exact duplicates. If I only had 3 variables, I could run this code to check for dupes:

```
proc sql;
  create table checkDupe as
  select count(*) as N, *
  from bigTable
  group by 1, 2, 3
  having N > 1;
quit;
```

However, with 250 variables, I don't want to type out `group by 1, 2, 3, ... , 250`.

The following `group by` statements don't work:

```
group by *

group by _ALL_

group by 1:250
```

Is there a concise way to group by all variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to produce macro variable for column names of dataset, then group in sql;

```
proc sql;
   select name into: name separate ',' from dictionary.columns where libname='SASHELP' and memname='CLASS';
quit;

proc sql;
   select count(*) as N,* from sashelp.class group by &name;
quit;
```

If just want to know whether there are complete duplicates in dataset, try this:

```
proc sort data=sashelp.class out=want nodup;
by _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code checking for duplicates returns a dataset that has all of the records where the key is NOT unique.  So the below returns four records:

```
data bigtable;
   input a b c d;
   datalines;
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1
1 2 1 1
1 2 2 1
1 2 2 2
;
run;

proc sql;
  create table checkDupe1 as
  select *,count(*) as N
  from bigTable
  group by 1, 2, 3
  having N > 1;
quit;
```

Assuming you don't need the `N` column, they easiest way in SAS to get a dataset of all non-unique rows is to use `PROC SORT` with the `NOUNIQUEKEY` option.  So below will return the same four records:

```
proc sort data=bigtable out=checkDupe2 nouniquekey ;
  by a b c ;
run ;
```

And the `BY` statement can be `BY _ALL_`, which will return the two records that are duplicates on all variables:

```
proc sort data=bigtable out=checkDupe3 nouniquekey ;
  by _all_ ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the desired output is each unique row from a SAS data set, no grouping is required. The easiest way to execute this in `PROC SQL` is with the `distinct` keyword.

For example:

```
data one;
   input a b c d;
   datalines;
   1 1 1 1
   1 1 1 1
   1 2 1 1
   1 2 3 4
   1 2 1 1
   ;
   run;
proc sql;
   select distinct * from one;
   run;
```

...produces the following output, where the two duplicate rows are eliminated.

[image]

Comment: I don't think that's the goal.  This doesn't identify duplicates.

Comment: @Quentin - it was difficult to tell from the OP what the desired output was. Either s/he wants to either eliminate the duplicates or know the duplicates. One answer already showed how to find the duplicates, so I posted an answer about eliminating them, starting my answer with "If the desired output is each unique row from a SAS data set..."

Comment: @LenGreski @Quentin Hey folks. Main goal was to identify which rows were exact duplicates. Having the count(*) variable was also useful for knowing exactly how many times a row was duplicated. Shenglin's suggestion of assigning variable names to a macro variable works, though I'm a little surprised there isn't a way to use `group by _all_` or something similar like one can do in PROC SORT. Thanks.

Comment: @hossibley - thanks for the feedback. There's no `_all_` in PROC SQL because the language is based on Structured Query Language, not the base SAS language. PROC SQL was originally designed to pass SQL statements to a relational database via SAS/ACCESS, and the remote relational databases do not know how to process `_all_`.